# jQuery onclick Event Not Firing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

So far this code has worked well in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, however during testing in IE, the onclick event is not firing in any version of IE. We've tested IE7—IE11.

The purpose of this code is to populate data selected from a drop-down into a text input box after clicking the "Update" button.

Here is a snippet:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="javascript:updateText();">
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
function updateText() {
//** Removes first option of select **//
$("option#ddlOptionsSelect.ng-binding").remove();

//** Populates option selected from dropdown into a text input field **//
document.getElementById("ctl00_cphMainContent_ucDialCustomization_Duc18264_StringTextBox").value =
$('#Dial_18269 #ddlOptions').val();
document.getElementById("ctl00_cphMainContent_ucDialCustomization_Duc18265_StringTextBox").value =
$('#Dial_18459 #ddlOptions').val();
document.getElementById("ctl00_cphMainContent_ucDialCustomization_Duc18266_StringTextBox").value =
$('#Dial_18456 #ddlOptions').val();
document.getElementById("ctl00_cphMainContent_ucDialCustomization_Duc18267_StringTextBox").value =
$('#Dial_18457 #ddlOptions').val();
document.getElementById("ctl00_cphMainContent_ucDialCustomization_Duc18268_StringTextBox").value =
$('#Dial_18460 #ddlOptions').val();
}
</script>
```

Any suggestions would be helpful as to why this script is not working in Internet Explorer but works in every other browser.

Comment: Why the `javascript:` label?

Comment: What if you remove the `javascript:updateText();` and instead, on the first line of your script tag, you say `$("input[type='button'][value='Update']").click(updateText);`?

Comment: @Haleyb Is the update button added to the page dynamically or is it always on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery for the event listener:

```
$("#<id>").on("click", function(){

    updateText();
});
```

You just need to ad an Id to the button.

```
<input type="button" value="Update" id="<id>">
```

ex.[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LucasCarioca/7yrf09c4/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to giving the input an id and attaching and onClick to it using jQuery, you can also simply change the onclick property of you input to **onclick="updateText();"**